# A button to protect all worksheets with a password and a button to unprotect

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Workbook with around 180 Worksheets.

I am trying to create 2 macros:

1) to protect all worksheets upon clicking a button

2) to unprotect all worksheet upon clicking a button, but asks user for the password

Here what i have already...

```
Sub Protect()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pwd As String

pwd = "xyz" ' Put your password here
For Each ws In Worksheets
   ws.Protect Password:=pwd, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
Next ws

End Sub
```

and to unprotect...

```
Sub UnProtect()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pwd As String

pwd = "xyz" ' Put your password here
For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.UnProtect Password:=pwd
Next ws

End Sub
```

The Protect macro works fine.

The UnProtect macro protects all worksheets, but i need it to ask the user for the password.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Look into `InputBox()`

Comment: @ScottCraner sorry... edited. I need help in asking the user for a password to unprotect all worksheets.

Comment: And I put how to do that in my new comment.  vba has `InputBox` just for that sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub UnProtect()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pwd As String
Dim myValue As Variant
pwd = "xyz" ' Put your password here
myValue = InputBox("What is the password?")
If myValue = pwd Then
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.UnProtect Password:=pwd
    Next ws
Else
    'do nothing or msgbox
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Umm, wouldn't it be simpler just to ask the user for the actual password (i.e. `pwd = InputBox("What is the password?")` rather than asking them for a second password that will then be checked to see whether the original password will be used?

Comment: @YowE3K well not sure if the OP wants a different password or if OP just wants the user to put in the pwd to unprotect. I've edit my post to just input the password to unprotect, he/she can change it if not.

Comment: Yeah, that edit makes sense (even better than just asking for the actual password - which would then probably give errors if the wrong value was supplied), so I'll +1 that